# Can you get a legendary new born dwellers

Tags: fallout-shelter

So I have one male and one female dwellers that have high special. If I let them make a baby dweller do I get a good chance of getting a good baby dweller?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it **is** possible for normal dwellers to give birth to a legendary dweller, altough it is **very** difficult. If you breed **2 maximum level** (level 50) **dwellers who also have a maxed out SPECIAL** (all stats are equal to or greater than 10).

Even at the maximum requirements, you still only have a 7% chance to obtain a legendary and a 13% chance to obtain a rare. All rares and legendaries born have a naturally very high intelligence.

Comment: Missing a lot of details.  Two max stat dwellers only have about 7% to get a Legendary, and 13% to get a Rare.  See the duplicate question that already has detailed answer.